# Bad value returned using EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to return a minimum `fiscalyear` with a grouping on `productid` using a subquery and the `EXISTS` operator.  For whatever reason, I am getting an arbitrary value from a set of fiscal years. The subquery returns the minimum `fiscalyear` but the outer query won't pick it up for the `UPDATE`.  Any ideas?

```
UPDATE#Temp
SET SALES_YEAR = sa.fiscalyear
FROM sales    sa
JOIN products p  ON p.id = sa.productid
JOIN #Temp    t  ON p.id = t.productid
WHERE exists ( select MIN(sa.fiscalyear),
                        sa.productid
               FROM sales    sa 
               JOIN products p  ON p.id = sa.productid
               JOIN #Temp    t  ON p.id = t.productid
               GROUP BY sa.productid
             )
```

Comment: Your `EXISTS` has no connection back to the parent query since you are re-using the table aliases, so it will return true or false for all records regardless of the values in the outer query.  What are you expecting `EXISTS` to tell you?

Comment: Your where exists subquery has nothing to do with the outer query. I'd change your table aliases, then make sure you do a where check when "outerquery x = innerquery y".

Comment: Don't use the same alias in your main query and your exists query.   Change one of the "sa" aliases to something else.

Comment: The clarification on the use of the EXISTS predicate is what I was after.  EXISTS is not being used correctly here for the result I was expecting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the join's *outside* the exists.  In addition, I assume you are using SQL Server.

Actually, I don't think you want `exists` at all.  Just use `=` like this:

```
UPDATE t
   SET SALES_YEAR = sa.fiscalyear 
FROM #Temp t
WHERE t.product_id = (Select TOP 1 sa.productid
                      FROM sales sa JOIN
                           products p
                           ON p.id = sa.productid
                      ORDER BY sa.fiscalyear
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
UPDATE  #Temp
SET     SALES_YEAR = A.fiscalyear
FROM  #Temp t 
JOIN (
    select  MIN(sa.fiscalyear),
            sa.productid
    FROM    sales sa
    JOIN    products p ON p.id = sa.productid
    JOIN    #Temp t ON p.id = t.productid
    GROUP BY sa.productid
) A ON T.PRODUCTID=A.PRODUCTID
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using SQL Server. This should do you:

```
UPDATE #Temp SET SALES_YEAR = x.fiscalyear
FROM #Temp t
join ( select product_id      = sa.productid ,
              fiscal_year = MIN( sa.fiscalyear )
       FROM sales    sa 
       JOIN products p  ON p.id = sa.productid
       JOIN #Temp    t  ON p.id = t.productid
       GROUP BY sa.productid
     ) x
```